# Excel VBA - Using Long Variables inside Range function while filtering

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on something, where I need to filter based on a criteria and it changes dynamically. I was able to find the number of rows and the column name of that particular column which I need to filter. Here goes my code,

```
Sub trial()

Dim colm As Long, Rowz As Long, Coladd As String
Dim nwb As Workbook, wb As Workbook
Dim nwk As Worksheet, wk As Worksheet, wk1 As Worksheet

colm = WorksheetFunction.Match("HeaderString", Sheets("Sheet1").Rows(1), 0)
Columns(colm).Select
Rowz = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, colm).End(xlUp).Row
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$colm.Address$1:$colm.Address$Rowz").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Mouse"
```

Now how do I get the range to filter by knowing the number of rows in that column and knowing that column number. My Criteria is a String - "Mouse". I am getting error at the last line of my code.

Kindly give me your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: [**`This`**](http://www.contextures.com/xlautofilter03.html) link will help you get going.

Comment: @ManishChristian Thanks for the link. The biggest problem for me is not knowing how to add the address inside the range functions. I saw a couple of other stack questions about converting column number to column address and even then I don't know whether I could use the range function with the Variables rather than the direct address

Comment: Refer to the range like this: `Range(Cells(1, colm), Cells(Rowz, colm)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Mouse"`

Comment: @Rory Thanks mate ! Got it. Kindly update the answer and I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a column number, the simplest method is to use two `Cells` calls inside the `Range` call:

```
Range(Cells(1, colm), Cells(Rowz, colm)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Mouse"
```

Note also that if you need to specify a worksheet for the range, you should qualify the Range and both Cells calls with that worksheet:

```
Sheets("Some sheet").Range(Sheets("Some sheet").Cells(1, colm), Sheets("Some sheet").Cells(Rowz, colm)).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="Mouse"
```

Comment: You can also use `With Sheets("Some sheet") ... End With` to cut down the length a bit

Comment: Yep, or use a variable like `ws`. I didn't want to distract from the main point though. ;)